# Sequence general convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Given a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that is increasing and is bounded show formally that $\{x_n\}$ converges.

So we must show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L < \infty$.

We know that $x_{n+1} > x_n$

So there also exists an $M$ such that $|x_n| < M$ for all $n$.

Suppose the sequence is unbounded. Then this means, $|x_n| > L$ for an $L > M$ for $n > N$.

This implies $|x_n| > L > M$ contradiction to $|x_n| < M$.

**Question:** Where did $x_{n+1} > x_n$ come in if it did at all?

Comment: Consider the set $\{a_n| n\in\mathbb N\}$. It is bounded, so it has a supremum $\alpha$, show the limit of $a_n$ is $\alpha$.

Comment: By the way, that proof makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean "suppose the sequence is unbounded"? You can't suppose that. It is bounded by hypothesis. If you seek a proof by contradiction, you should start with "suppose that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge". But I think a direct proof will be more natural here.

Comment: Your attempt at a proof by contradiction does not make sense. You started by supposing one of the assumptions (boundedness of the sequence) was false, instead of supposing the conclusion was false.

Answer (score 1):

If you want proof by contradiction, you need something like this:

Assume $x_n$ does not converge, hence $\not \exists \ L$ s.t. $x_n$ is within $\varepsilon-$bound of $L$. But by bounded condition we know that $x_n <M< \infty \ \forall n$. Now consider certain bound $\varepsilon_2$ s.t. $M-x_{n_1}<\varepsilon_1$ or $|x_{n_1} - M|<\varepsilon_1$ if you wish to be more consistent with the notation. But by monotonicity $x_{n_1}<x_{n_2}< \ldots x_{n_k} \ \forall k \in Z_{+}$, i.e. all terms after $n_1$ are within $\varepsilon_1-$bound of M.

Hence $|x_n-M|<\varepsilon_1$. Now set $M=L, \varepsilon=\varepsilon_1$ thus proving convergence of $x_n$.

Comment: I meant does not converge of course, fixed.

Comment: If $M$ is some arbitrary upper bound for $x_n$, why must there be an $x_n$ near $M$? Putting it another way, it need not be possible to make your $\epsilon_1$ arbitrarily small, and if you can't do that, there is no contradiction.

Comment: I think the intention here is that $\;M=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{x_n\}\;$ . Otherwise the clain in the second line of the second parraph may be false.

Comment: so $\sup$ and limit have to be the same?

Comment: @Alex That is correct, if $x_n$ is increasing and bounded then it converges to its supremum.

Comment: So 'proof by contradiction' is almost trivial then

Answer (score 0):

That is the proof you are looking for:

Let $x := \sup\{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. Then we have that $x < \infty$ because $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Since $x$ is the supremum we find for every $\epsilon > 0$ a $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ with $\vert x - x_{n_0} \vert < \epsilon$.

Because $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is monotone, we have that
$\vert x - x_n \vert \leq \vert x - x_{n_0} \vert < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Hence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x$.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Using the monotonic increasing condition you can easily dispose of that absolute value...and make things clearer, too.